Microsoft SSIS OLE DB for SQL Anywhere 17
I am using Visual Studio 2022 and I have created a SSIS package that connects to a Sybase Anywhere database using the SQL Anywhere OLE DB Provider 17. I have created the OLE DB connection and it tests OK. I have created an OLE DB source and when I preview the data it works fine. BUT when I debug the package it doesn't run, the data flow task shows as running but it does not start any of the tasks within.

If I open the Event Viewer in Windows it shows the

The description for Event ID 12288 from source SQLISPackage160 cannot
be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed
on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can
install or repair the component on the local computer.
If the event originated on another computer, the display information
had to be saved with the event.
The following information was included with the event:
Package
The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the SQL Anywhere drivers but it did not help.
Any ideas? I need OLEDB to use the Lookup function.

Apologies,  I am using Visual Studio 2022

I have the same problem.

I changed Connection from OLEDB to ODBC instead.

I setup on ODBC Data Sources (User DSN) with SQL Anyware 17 driver.

On SSIS package:
3.1. Click right on Connection Managers.
3.2. Select New connection.
3.3. Select Type ODBC.
3.4. Click New and Select System data source name from 2. and type User Name and Password. and test connection. and User ODBC Source instead OLE DB Source.



Please review and [edit] for readability. Use this info https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and [ask] and [tour]. Also aboid the impression of "me too".

@karel thanks, but I would like to use the Lookup function, which is only supported by an OLEDB source, Have you found any fixes yet?

@Greg 1. In your data flow task, set up an ODBC source as usual to pull the initial dataset. 2. After the ODBC source, add the Lookup transformation. 3. Inside the Lookup transformation, configure it to use an OLE DB connection (set up an additional OLE DB connection manager if needed) that connects to the SQL Anywhere database for the lookup table. This approach will allow you to retain the performance and compatibility benefits of ODBC while still leveraging the Lookup feature that relies on OLE DB. For additional information please comment that you want me to post it as a new answer.

@karel, unfortunately if I add an OLEDB Connector for SQL Anywhere 17 then the Data Flow Task will hang on Debug. The only workaround that I have found is to set the RetainSameConnection and DelayValidation options to TRUE. Not sure if that would be good practice though

Setting both RetainSameConnection and DelayValidation to TRUE is a common approach for SSIS packages facing similar issues. For read-only scenarios (like lookups), this should work fine as long as you monitor for any unintended side effects like locking.
